# Drawing XBM bitmaps on Arduino

Tags: bitmap, arduino, bit-manipulation, avr

I am trying to parse an XBM bitmap on Arduino, with no luck at all (expect <16x16 bitmaps). After much searching, researching and tinkering I have come up to this function. I'm sure I'm reading the bytes correctly (tested), there is something wrong with the conversion though.

```
void bitmap(int x, int y, uint16_t *bitmap, uint8_t w, uint8_t h) {
  uint16_t dots, msb;
  uint16_t col, row;

  msb = 1 << (w - 1);
  for (row = 0; row < h; row++) {
    dots = pgm_read_word(bitmap + row);
    //Serial.print(dots, HEX);
    //Serial.println(" ");
    for (col = 0; col < w; col++) {
      if (dots & (msb >> col))
        Serial.print("#"); //toolbox.setPixel(x, y, 1, false);
      else
        Serial.print("'"); //toolbox.setPixel(x, y, 0, false);
    }
    Serial.println("");
  }
}
```

This is the bitmap I'm trying to show. It has a size of 32x32 pixels. Images of 16x16 or less are displayed correctly.

```
// 32x32
uint16_t medium[] PROGMEM = {
  0xffff, 0xffff, 0x0000, 0x8000, 0xffff, 0xffff, 0x0001, 0x0000, 0xffff,
  0xffff, 0x0000, 0x8000, 0xffff, 0xffff, 0x0001, 0x0000, 0xffff, 0xffff,
  0x0000, 0x8000, 0xffff, 0xffff, 0x0001, 0x0000, 0xffff, 0xffff, 0x0000,
  0x8000, 0xffff, 0xffff, 0x0001, 0x0000, 0xffff, 0xffff, 0x0000, 0x8000,
  0xffff, 0xffff, 0x0001, 0x0000, 0xffff, 0xffff, 0x0000, 0x8000, 0xffff,
  0xffff, 0x0001, 0x0000, 0xffff, 0xffff, 0x0000, 0x8000, 0xffff, 0xffff,
  0x0001, 0x0000, 0xffff, 0xffff, 0x0000, 0x8000, 0xffff, 0xffff, 0x0001,
  0x0000 };
```

This is a PNG of the bitmap for reference: [image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
msb = 1 << (w - 1);
[snip]
if (dots & (msb >> col))
```

This logic only works if `w` is less than 16.

EDIT: in response to comment.

Actually, that is the part that needs fixing. It is true that you are going to use uint16_t, but you need to work out a way to turn the 16 bit integers into a stream of bits. Right now, it only works when the rows are exactly 16 bits wide.

I would do something to get the next bit from the stream. I would use a variable to keep track of where I am in the current word, and then get the next word when needed using another variable.

```
void bitmap(int x, int y, uint16_t *bitmap, uint8_t w, uint8_t h) {
  uint16_t dots = 0, current_mask = 0;
  uint16_t col, row, next_word = 0;

  for (row = 0; row < h; row++) {
    for (col = 0; col < w; col++) {
      current_mask >>= 1;
      if (0 == current_mask) {
          current_mask = 1 << 15;
          dots = pgm_read_word(bitmap + next_word);
          ++next_word;
      }

      if (dots & current_mask)
        Serial.print("#"); //toolbox.setPixel(x, y, 1, false);
      else
        Serial.print("'"); //toolbox.setPixel(x, y, 0, false);

    }
    Serial.println("");
  }
}
```

I haven't tried this, and there are some details to take of with indexing memory and bit shifting. Good luck.